# How to get Parent Asset values

Tags: apex, soql

I have the following lines of code

```
    List<SObject> sObjectList =[SELECTId,Name,SerialNumber,Product2Id,Product2.Name,Quantity,Status,AccountId,Account.Name,Parent.SerialNumber From Asset Where AccountId = 'some account id' LIMIT 1000];
    for (sObject sObj: sObjectList) {
        sObject sObjProd2 = sObj.getSObject('Product2');
        String prodName = (String)sObjProd2.get('Name');
        sObject sObjParent = sObj.getSObject('Parent'); 
        String parentSrNo = (String)sObjParent.get('SerialNumber');
     }
```

The above query works fine and it returns me the following data

```
[{
    "Id": "02i46000000YeKNAA0",
    "Name": "Asset 2",
    "SerialNumber": "6789",
    "Product2Id": "01t460000012C6JAAU",
    "Quantity": 1.00,
    "Status": "Registered",
    "AccountId": "0014600000DWUKLAA5",
    "Product2": {
        "Name": "GenWatt Diesel10kW",
        "Id": "01t460000012C6JAAU"
    },
    "Account": {
        "Name": "Test1",
        "Id": "0014600000DWUKLAA5"
    },
    "Parent": {
        "SerialNumber": "9812",
        "Id": "02i46000000YeYcAAK"
    }
}]
```

But when I execute line #5(sObject sObjParent = sObj.getSObject('Parent');), I get the following error:

> System.SObjectException: Invalid relationship Parent for Asset

How can I get the value of `Parent.SerialNumber` in Apex?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to access this data dynamically. Static access should work just as well:

```
for (Asset record : [SELECT ... FROM Asset WHERE ... LIMIT ...])
{
    String serialNumber = record.Parent.SerialNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian for the response.
Static access will not work for me as at the run time only I am getting to know the name of the field that I need to fetch the value for. SerialNumber was just an example. Field names are coming from the fieldset on Asset and user can add any field to the field set. I will know about it only at the run time. Hence, I have to access this data dynamically.